# Unable to set custom path(user defined path) of merge module file path in Basic MSI Project in InstallShiled?

Tags: merge-module, installshield-2014

I have merge module (.msm) files.
I want to add this file in Basic MSI Project.

I found that InstallShiled has fixed path of merge module folder.
Every time I have to move built merge module in fixed Path of merge module folder.

For Example Fixed path of merge module.

```
C:\InstallShield 2014 Projects\MergeModules,C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield\2014\Modules\i386,C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield\2014\Objects,C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield\2014\Modules\i386\Japanese,C:\Program Files (x86)\InstallShield\2014\Modules\i386\German;
```

Please follow below step to find path variable in InstallShield project.

1. Open Basic MSI Project
2. Switch to "Installation Designer" Tab.
3. Go to "Media" and Extract "Media.
4. Click on "Path Variables".

PFA: Screenshots for more info.

[image: Path Variable]

```
"<IsProjectFolder>" is my current directory path of InstallShield project.

I am trying to add "<IsProjectFolder>" in merge module tab.

InstallShiled Throws error.
```

PFA: Screenshot for more info.

[image: Merge Module Tab]

Please help...
How to add customize path for merge module in InstallShiled?

Comment: Note that the first several locations are separatd by a comma `,` instead of a semicolon `;`. Have you tried using a comma for your new one?

Comment: Hi Michael, I have tried comma (,) instead of semicolon (;) but it is get same error.